# Paid = NO but order submitted

Tags: expresso-store

My only payment method is paypal, but some orders are getting submitted with no payment.  How is this possible that an order can be submitted with no payment?

Comment: To avoid down voting, you need to add more information, such as what E-commerce system you are using. You may also need to post code snippets.

Comment: Hi Peter. Here are just a few examples of things you need to add to your question before we can help you - What e-commerce add-on are you using? What payment methods do you have set up? What have you tried so far? Screenshots and code snippets are helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Orders can be submitted without being paid but they will show up incomplete. This allows people to come back and pay for an order at a late date (if there card fails or similar). This also allows for certain situations where you need to authorize only and then capture payments after the order has shipped.

Comment: sorry missed that I am using Store in EE2

Comment: As I said in my original answer orders can show up unpaid in your Store's order history but they should be marked as Incomplete and should not have a status of Paid. If you orders are coming though as paid without a correlating charge then that is a completely different case.